# Unable to login using Web3 Modal SDK, login provider: email_passwordless

Tags: wallet-connect, web3auth

I was trying with the email_passwordless in web-modal SDK. But continuously facing this error. It seems like a CORS error. But I also tried with the local React project. It seems ok in there and shows the OTP perfectly.

GIT URL:
https://github.com/Web3Auth/web3auth-pnp-examples/tree/main/web-modal-sdk/evm/react-evm-modal-example

Looking into this example:
https://web3auth.io/docs/sdk/pnp/web/modal/whitelabel#example-1

Check-in here: Sign in with the Email field.
https://shop.bcl.xyz/collections/the-masked-singer-experience

[image]

```
let web3authh = new window.Modal.Web3Auth({
      chainConfig: {
        chainNamespace: "eip155",
        rpcTarget: "https://polygon-rpc.com",
        blockExplorer: "https://polygonscan.com/",
        chainId: "0x89",
        dChainId: "137",
        displayName: "Polygon Mainnet",
        ticker: "matic",
        tickerName: "Matic",
        decimals: 18,
      },
      clientId: clientIdObj.cyan,
      web3AuthNetwork: "cyan", // cyan for prod, mainnet for stage and testnet for dev
      enableLogging: true,
      uiConfig: {
        mode: "dark",
        loginMethodsOrder: ["google", "apple", "twitter", "discord"],
        appLogo: __APP_LOGO,
        modalZIndex: "99998",
        defaultLanguage: "en",
      },
    });

const openloginAdapter = new window.OpenloginAdapter.OpenloginAdapter({
      loginSettings: {
        mfaLevel: "none", // this is imp
      },

      adapterSettings: {
        network: "cyan",
        uxMode: "redirect",
        _iframeUrl: "https://fox.web3auth.com",
        whiteLabel: {
          appName: "Maskverse",
          theme: {
            primary: "#9333EA",
          },
          logoLight: __APP_LOGO,
          logoDark: __APP_LOGO,
          defaultLanguage: "en",
        },
      },
    });

const openloginConfig = {
      "openlogin": {
        label: "openlogin",
        loginMethods: {
          // email_passwordless: {
          //   name: "email_passwordless",
          //   showOnModal: false
          // },
          sms_passwordless: {
            name: "sms_passwordless",
            showOnModal: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
await web3authh.initModal({ modalConfig: openloginConfig });
```